# Setting margin in beamer theme on a slide basis

Tags: beamer, margins, themes

I'm developing a Latex Beamer theme that will support several slide templates. According to user command,

\slidenormal

\slidemphasis

...

The generated template may provide different margin sizes. I think that the geometry package is the right resource to do the job but I can't figure out which \defbeamertemplate I can put the \newgeometry commands.

Any idea? Or a different way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The theme user could ask things like: \slidenormal \begin{frame} ... \end{frame}, \slideemph \begin{frame} ... \end{frame} and the displayed slide will have different left margins (2cm for normal, 1cm for emph).